# Enabling HTTPS on EC2 instance inside AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying an Expressjs in a Docker container via Elastic Beanstalk. My app checks `req.secure` for every request to make sure that it is using HTTPS. It won't allow access to the app if it isn't HTTPS. I have followed all the instructions in the AWS docs to configure my Load Balancer to accept HTTPS and for it to communicate via HTTPS to my EC2 instance.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-endtoend.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-docker.html

I managed to get HTTPS working on the Load Balancer, but it doesn't seem to be using HTTPS to talk to my Docker Container. Does anyone have any ideas?

My listeners in the load balancer are:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elb:listener:443:
    InstancePort: 443
    InstanceProtocol: HTTPS
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:
    Application Healthcheck URL: HTTPS:443/
```

and

```
option_settings:
 aws:elb:listener:443:
  SSLCertificateId: arn:aws:iam::######:server-certificate/cert_name
  ListenerProtocol: HTTPS
```

Edit:

I don't know if this will help, but this is how I set up my EC2 instance:

```
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Auth:
          type: "s3"
          buckets: ["elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-#########"]
          roleName:
            "Fn::GetOptionSetting":
              Namespace: "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
              OptionName: "IamInstanceProfile"
              DefaultValue: "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"

files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/https.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      # HTTPS Server

      server {
        listen 443;
        server_name localhost;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
          proxy_pass http://docker;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;

          proxy_set_header Connection "";
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
      }

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    authentication: "S3Auth"
    source: https://s3.amazonaws.com/<url_to_private_key>

 /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    authentication: "S3Auth"
    source: https://s3.amazonaws.coom/<url_to_cert>
```

Comment: What port is your docker container using for your App?

Comment: @error2007s My Docker container exposes port 4040. According to the instructions on AWS's docs, The ngnix proxy on the EC2 instance to use https. I set it to listen to 443. I also checked the headers actually being received by my app and ```{ "x-forwarded-proto": "https" }```. The ```req.secure``` returns false inside my app though. I am not sure as to why.

Comment: Is port 443 open in your Docker Security group?

Comment: @error2007s I believe it is yes.

Comment: Can you upload the screenshot of the listeners of your AWS ELB from the AWS console?

Comment: @error2007s You mean from the EC2 console or Elastic Beanstalk console? I didn't set up any listeners via ELB console. My listeners on the EC2 console are:


    `Load Balancer Protocol: HTTPS`
   `Load Balancer Port: 443` 
    `Instance Protocol: HTTPS`
    `Instance Port: 443`
    `SSL Certificate: <my ssl certificate uploaded via IAM>`

Comment: Ok change the instance protocol to HTTP and Instance port to 4040 in the listeners I guess it will work